# Int object is not iterable error calculating travel costs

Tags: python

Here is my code. I keep getting the message that `"int" object is not interable`. I'm not sure what I did wrong though?

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return(nights*140)
hotel_cost(1)

def plane_ride_cost (city):
    ["Charlotte" == 183, "Tampa" == 220, "Los_Angeles" == 475,
    "Pittsburgh" == 222]
    if (city) == "Charlotte":
       return 183
    elif (city) == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif (city) == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
    elif (city) == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222 

plane_ride_cost("Tampa")

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost= 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost
rental_car_cost(1)

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return sum(rental_car_cost(6) + plane_ride_cost("Tampa"))
```

Comment: Please do come up with a better question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum()` expects an iterable, a sequence of things to sum. But you gave it an integer:

```
rental_car_cost(6) + plane_ride_cost("Tampa")
```

already adds up the two integer results.

Remove the `sum()` call, you don't need it here, as `+` is perfectly serviceable:

```
def trip_cost(city, days):
    return rental_car_cost(6) + plane_ride_cost("Tampa")
```

You probably want to make use of the `city` and `days` parameters there rather than hard-code the days to 6 and the city to `"Tampa"`.

That list definition with city names as the first line of the `plane_ride_cost()` function is redundant, by the way; it only produces a list of `False` values (none of the city name strings are equal to the number following):

```
>>> ["Charlotte" == 183, "Tampa" == 220, "Los_Angeles" == 475,
...  "Pittsburgh" == 222]
[False, False, False, False]
```

and you are otherwise ignoring it anyway. You could define it as a dictionary perhaps? Like this:

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    plane_tickets = {
        "Charlotte": 183,
        "Tampa": 220,
        "Los_Angeles": 475,
        "Pittsburgh": 222
    }
    return plane_tickets[city]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to create a dictionary but I had clearly mistaken [] for {} and that is why I thought it would work. Thank you for pointing it out and helping me figure this out.